# WPF Run a Storyboard in Parent Window from Child User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a Button in a Usercontrol. This Usercontrol is placed in a Window.

I want to Start an animation of `Grid.Width` in the Window (Parent) when the Button in UserControl(Child) is clicked.

I know I could do a dependency property "buttonclicked" in the usercontrol and trigger it from the window, but I think there are better solutions?

Something like this (Pseudocode). But how to access the Storyboard of the parent?

```xml
<Window>
    <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
                    <ColumnDefinition.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardOfMainMenu"/>
                    </ColumnDefinition.Resources>
                </ColumnDefinition>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
  <MyUserControl>
</Window>

<MyUserControl>
    <Button>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{x:Reference Name=StoryboardOfMainMenu}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</MyUserControl>
```

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's best if one screen (window or user control) does not try to inspect or manipulate the UI elements of another screen.  I would do this by having the child window raise an event, and have the child's owner respond to the event (e.g., by kicking off the storyboard).  Ideally, the button would bind to a command that fires off an event in the child's view model, the parent view model would relay it, and the parent view would respond.

Comment: change `<ColumnDefinition Width="100" >` to `<ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="YourColumnDefinitionName">` , then you can get the Storyboard  like this: `Storyboard st=YourWindowName.YourColumnDefinitionName.FindResource("StoryboardOfMainMenu") as Storyboard ;`